# Setting up User account GPO using VB scripting

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to write a script which satisfies the following when setting up a user account:

They must have a 
- Minimum password length of 8
- Max password age of 180 days
- to remember the last 4 passwords each user has used.
- to lock out for 60 minutes if password is entered wrong over 10 times

Here is my code so far:

```
set dom = GetObject ("WinNT://CHANGE")

'set minimum password length
 Dom.Put "MinimumPasswordLegth", 8

'Set Maximum Password Age 180 days.... 180*86400 (86,400 represents 24hours in seconds)
Dom.Put "MaxPasswordAge", 86400*180

'Set Password History Length
Dom.Put "PasswordHistoryLength", 4
'Set Lockout
dom.Put "MaxBadPasswordsAllowed", 10
dom.Put "AutoUnlockInterval", 60*60
dom.Put "LockoutObservationInterval", 60*10

Dom.SetInfo

'Confirm the Change
WScript.Echo("MinPasswordLength")
WScript.Echo("PasswordHistoryLength: " & dom.PasswordHistoryLength)

'Confirm Lockout
WScript.Echo dom.Get("MaxBadPasswordsAllowed")
WScript.Echo dom.Get("AutoUnlockInterval")
WScript.Echo dom.Get ("LockoutObservationInterval")
```

I cannot figure out why this doesn't run

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where did you find documentation saying this was possible?

Comment: from a book called, Microsoft® PowerShell, VBScript, and JScript